# meteor 0.8.3 + iron router = infinite loop inside waitOn hook

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I try to move from meteor 0.8.2 to meteor 0.8.3 but i have a huge problem :
in the browser, the update leads to an infinite loop on waitOn hooks.

i have 3 main routes :
 * /
 * /list
 * /item/:_id

the 2 first works well. On /list i have a waitOn hooks that subscribe to only one Collection.
But on the last route, nothing works :
the browser loop over waitOn hook and it freeze the browser really quickly.

Here is the controller :

```
SearchController = RouteController.extend({
    template: "mainApp",

    waitOn: function funcClientRouteWaitOnSearch() {
    console.log('waitOn', this.ready(), Annonces.find().count());

    if (Lbc.Annonces.Animation.previousSearch !== Lbc.Annonces.Animation.currentSearch
        && Annonces.find({"searchIndex": Session.get('selectedSearch')}).count()) {
        console.log('Use cache from SubsManager');
        Lbc.Annonces.Animation.inCache = true;
    } else {
        console.log('NO CACHE in SubsManager');
    }

    return [
            subsSearch.subscribe("Annonces",
                                 Session.get('selectedSearch'),
                                 Session.get('selectedFilter'),
                                 Session.get('selectedLocation'),
                                 Session.get('loadMore'), function funcSubAnnoncesOnReady() {}),

            subsSearchList.subscribe("PostCodes",
                                     Session.get("selectedSearch")),

            Meteor.subscribe("SearchIndexIds")
    ];
  },

  onRun: function funcClientRouteOnRunSearch() {
    console.log('onRun', this.ready(), Annonces.find().count());

    Lbc.Annonces.Animation.previousSearch = Lbc.Annonces.Animation.currentSearch;
    Lbc.Annonces.Animation.currentSearch = this.params._id;
    Lbc.Session.prepareSession(this.params._id);
  },

  onBeforeAction: function funcClientRouteBeforeSearch() {
    console.log('onBeforeAction', this.ready(), Annonces.find().count());

    Meteor.subscribe("counters-annonces",
                     Session.get("selectedSearch"),
                     Session.get('selectedFilter'),
                     Session.get('selectedLocation'),
                     Session.get('lastChangeStatusTime')
                    );

    Meteor.subscribe("counters-new-annonces",
                     Session.get('selectedSearch'),
                     Session.get('selectedLocation')
                    );

  },

  action: function funcClientRouteActionSearch() {
    console.log('action', this.ready(), Annonces.find().count());

    var searchIndexInfo = SearchIndexIds.findOne(this.params._id);
    if (searchIndexInfo) {
      searchAnnonces.Templater.setCurrentProvider(searchIndexInfo.url);
    }

    this.render();

    filters.animation.call(this);
    filters.notify.call(this);
  },

  onStop: function funcClientRouteStopSearch() {
    console.log('onStop', this.ready(), Annonces.find().count());

    Lbc.Annonces.Animation.doAnimation = false;
  }
});
```

In the onRun hook there is a call to prepareSession that will set all required Sessions var for that routes. Then waitOn is called in infinite loop.

I tried to put the subscription inside onBeforeAction hook and it works, but it's not the behaviour i need. Any idea of a solution ? 
I removed SubsManager package to see if it was the source of the problem but it's not.

i opened an issue : [iron-router issue 741](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/741)

a sample version of the app is available here : [moveto083](http://moveto083.meteor.com) and with user test123/test123

Thanks for help

Comment: Don't you think this is because you're both subscribing and fetching data from `Annonces` collection in the same place? It's generally wrong to do the both things within a singe computation. It's like using `Session.set('key', Session.get('key') + 1)` within `Deps.autorun` ;)

Comment: I don't know, in fact i never had the problem with previous version. With subsManager, the collection has data even in waitOn hooks that's why i check if the current route will have new item or if i already have items to display (this is to enable/disable animations when displaying items)

Comment: i've tested removing the uses of inside the waitOnd Annonces.find(...) but it confirm that it still fail without it